# Duplicate values are inserted into table though @Id used for one of property in entity class in jpa

Tags: jpa

Used @Id annotation for one field in entity class and inserted the same data twice using jpa persist method. Both the times data inserted successfully i.e duplicate data inserted.
@Id represents primary key and primary key should be unique but here duplicates values are inserted.
Note: i'm not specified the primary key constraint at DB side while creating table.
Below is the entity class.

```
`@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
private BigDecimal employeeid;
private String firstname;`
private String lastname;
private long salary;
```

// getters and setters here
   }

Please explain why jpa entity allowing duplicate records though @Id property used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify primary key Generation strategy. This strategy will be used by the JPA to generate the Primary Key.

The Generation strategy may vary, it depends on the database vendor you are using.

e.g. for MYSQL server annotate primary key like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private BigDecimal employeeId;
```

This will generate an incremental primary key for the new entity.

Answering to your question,
ORM not gonna tell you about a duplicate entry for the same entity persisted twice. ORM depends on primary key for that.

You should add Unique constraints in your columns. This will throw SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException exception wrapped in avax.persistence.PersistenceException if you persist logical duplicate entity. Catch this exception and handle it.

Comment: This answer is still valid in Aug, 2021.

Comment: Can you please answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68852122/how-to-prevent-duplicate-records-in-mysql-using-annotations-when-using-hibernate/68852841#68852841