# How to prevent duplicate records in Mysql using annotations when using Hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, annotations

It's my day 2 in `Java Hibernate`. I'm learning form this YouTube tutorial:

[Hibernate Tutorial | Configuration File](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HslkJXvqlWs&list=PLsyeobzWxl7qBZtsEvp_n2A7sJs2MpF3r&index=6&ab_channel=Telusko)

I'm carefully following each and every step. My problem is that I'm able to push same record many times:

```
mysql> select * from Alien;
+------+-------+--------+
| aid  | aname | acolor |
+------+-------+--------+
|  101 | Navin | Green  |
|  101 | Navin | Green  |
|  101 | Navin | Green  |
|  101 | Navin | Green  |
|  101 | Navin | Green  |
|  101 | Navin | Green  |
|  101 | Navin | Green  |
+------+-------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here are my files.

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">cosmonauts</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">
            update
        </property>
        <property name="show_sql=true"></property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Alien.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Alien {  // POJO
    
    @Id
    private int aid;
    private String aname;
    private String acolor;
    
    ... //getters and setters
}
```

**App.java** // Main class

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Alien telusko = new Alien();
        telusko.setAid(101);
        telusko.setAname("Navin");
        telusko.setAcolor("Green");
        
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Alien.class);
        
        StandardServiceRegistry reg = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory sf = configuration.buildSessionFactory(reg);
        
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(telusko);
        tx.commit();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.student.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>StudentSystem</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Did I misunderstand something. Please correct my mistake.

On console I'm getting this:

```
Aug 19, 2021 10:43:44 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.5.6.Final
Aug 19, 2021 10:43:45 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
Aug 19, 2021 10:43:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Aug 19, 2021 10:43:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb]
Aug 19, 2021 10:43:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
Aug 19, 2021 10:43:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Aug 19, 2021 10:43:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Aug 19, 2021 10:43:45 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Aug 19, 2021 10:43:45 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@27e7c77f] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Aug 19, 2021 10:43:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
```

Please pitch in.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this answer.
In summary, you need to be using a strategy to generate the Id

[Duplicate values are inserted into table though @Id used for one of property in entity class in jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418703/duplicate-values-are-inserted-into-table-though-id-used-for-one-of-property-in)

Comment: I appreciate your help but this is just a workaround. what if i need to handle exception. Also I wold write test cases.

Answer (score 0):

The correct hibernate property for `Hibernate 5.5.6.Final` is `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`. See Hibernate Documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html). So, please try replacing in your `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

with

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

It's the generated DDL script which should ensure that there are no duplicates. With the incorrect property in place, Hibernate won't be able to update DDL for you.

**Update**

I tried and the application is working as expected and is generating the primary key constraints. Below are the generated logs -

```
Hibernate: create table Alien (aid integer not null, acolor varchar(255), aname varchar(255), primary key (aid)) engine=MyISAM
Hibernate: insert into Alien (acolor, aname, aid) values (?, ?, ?)
Aug 21, 2021 4:36:13 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.5.6.Final
Aug 21, 2021 4:36:13 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
Aug 21, 2021 4:36:13 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Aug 21, 2021 4:36:13 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb]
Aug 21, 2021 4:36:13 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
Aug 21, 2021 4:36:13 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Aug 21, 2021 4:36:13 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Sat Aug 21 16:36:14 IST 2021 WARN: This connection is using TLSv1.1 which is now deprecated and will be removed in a future release of Connector/J.
Aug 21, 2021 4:36:14 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Aug 21, 2021 4:36:14 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@411a5965] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Aug 21, 2021 4:36:14 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
```

I changed these 3 lines in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file -

```
    <!-- used MySQL5Dialect in place of MySQLDialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <!-- corrected the config. It must not be generating SQL statements because of it -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

Notice that the generated logs has `primary key (aid)` now. If this constraint is present in your generated SQL, then it will start throwing `ConstraintViolationException` as you expect it to be.

Comment: Nope. Didnt work. I can still see duplicate records. 

`mysql> select * from Alien;
+------+---------+--------+
| aid  | aname   | acolor |
+------+---------+--------+
|  103 | Mridula | Red    |
|  103 | Mridula | Red    |
|  103 | Mridula | Red    |
+------+---------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: @Tanzeel Can you try dropping the table and start all over again. I suspect schema can't be updated due to already duplicate records.

Comment: Dropped and recreated the table. Didnt work. Still I'm able to save same records again and again.

Comment: Is a skype call possible. I'll share the screen. My timezone is Bangalore, India

Comment: Can you update generated schema in your question ? Do you see primary key there ?

Comment: No issues. I can understand.

Comment: which part is the schema. Plz clarify. I'm new to this env.

Comment: Did you mean `hibernate.cfg.xml` ?. If yes, then updated the same.

Comment: @Tanzeel I meant DDL which you can get from MySQL. Otherwise, try to change the `Alien` Class Name. If you name it to something else, a new table should get generated with that name.

Comment: nothing seems to be working out. I'm still able to push same records on and on.

Comment: @Tanzeel I updated the answer. It's working as expected for me.

Comment: With same version of hibernate ?

Comment: Yes I used the same version of Hibernate.